# How are regular medals tracked in Battlefield 1?

Tags: battlefield-1

I'm able to track the "5" weekly medals, but none of my other regular medals for game modes, weapons, or classes, etc. are working/ tracking the stats. Does anyone have this issue as well? How do I get the regular medals to begin following my progress?

Comment: I was under the impression that you could only track/earn credit the weekly offerings. I hope I'm wrong, but I guess we'll see!

Answer (score 1):

Battlefield 1 is a bit different from the other games in the series. Service Stars and Ribbons are unchanged from previous titles, but Medals are only available on the weekly basis with the set of choices. The Medals can only be worked one at a time.

There is also codex entries, but those are relatively easy to obtain, and only once. They provide a neat history lesson, though.